# Difference between ADO connection and SQLConnection c#

Tags: sql, ado

I am currently trying to connect to a database using SQL (I do not manage this database)

I am having to use ADODB.connection to connect to the database setting a driver and an option for the connection, what I dont understand is why an ADO connection is any different to a standard SQLConnection with regards to connecting, whenever I try and connect using a standard SQLConnection with a connection string, I can no longer set the driver I want it to use, and also dont get an option for the type of connection, and I get error 40, names and pipes, however I know I can connect because ADO allows me to connect.

I just know more about SQLConnection and how it works so I would like to use that if possible.

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So after pulling my hair out a little, it seems that SQLConnect is completely different to MySQLConnection in c# You need to download the SQL connector from here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/ and then add the library to the c# project references.

Then simply add "using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;" and you can then basically use MySQLConnection the same way you would use SQLConnection